# How to accelerate ajax http request using Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, request

hey guys well when am gonna take an appointment and send request  to that server https://algeria.blsspainvisa.com/appointment.php its keep loading without giving me any answer 
any solutions to speed up that request to server to  get the answer fast

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        BLS FAST REQUEST
// @require      https://algeria.blsspainvisa.com/french/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
// @include      https://*.blsspainvisa.com/*/appointment.php
// @include      https://*.blsspainvisa.com/appointment.php
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @connect     blsspainvisa.com
// ==/UserScript==

GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:     'GET',
    url:        'https://Algeria.blsspainvisa.com/appointment.php',
    onload:     function (responseDetails) {
```

Comment: If the server is slow, that's a problem with the server, not with you, there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: Yep  its from server but is there any solution for that ? like accelerate that request  ajax http

Comment: No. The problem is on the server - nothing the client can do can change it.

Comment: An "accelerated" request won't help much if the response is slow

Comment: hmm its okey thanks Guys